# Responsive media query overwriting

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have wrote this media query for targeting 240*480 resolution

```
@media only screen and (min-width:240px) 
                   and (max-width:480px) {
    .speech-bubble-container {
        right: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

another media query for 321*480 resolutions

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) 
                   and (max-width : 480px) 
                   and (orientation :landscape) {
    .speech-bubble-container {
        right: -48px !important;
    }
}
```

but when i test the website in 240*480 portrait mode device its right:0 property is not overwriting the right:-48px; -- how to achieve this?

I want to excute right:0 for 240*480 resolution device but instead of this it is overwriting by right:-48px;

I am new to responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your media queries like the following: **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6HzY/)** for reference. Resize the fiddle window to see it in action. When it's on portrait mode (width less than 320px), the `right: 0;` will be applicable while on landscape mode (width greater than 321px), the `right: -48px;` will be applied.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    .speech-bubble-container {
        right: 0 !important;
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
    .speech-bubble-container {
        right: -48px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries overlap. The first one it doesn't say '240x480'. It says from a range of minimum width of 240px to maximum width of 480 use these styles.

380px width falls in the above.

Comment: I am new to this responsive design could you please tell me how to write this?